# How do I merge the body and the legs?

Tags: rigidbody

So this is my first time modeling a body and I've made the torso and the legs in different objects so I wouldn't mess it up, now I don't know how to merge/connect them to make it a single object and the "Subsurf" modifier doesn't appear on the modifiers tab, I also don't know how parent vertexs work nor how to subordinate other vertexs.
Here's a picture of the objects I'm talking about:[image]

Comment: Select the objects, press Ctrl J. The objects are now one.

Comment: I select both of them on the "Scene collection" and press Ctrl + J but it doesn't do anything

Comment: Do these actions in the 3d viewport

Comment: Which one is that?

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

Select your leg on Object mode, change to Edit mode
press "A" to select the whole leg
copy with ctrl+c
unselect clicking everywhere else

turn into object mode again
hide the leg you've just selected before with "H" and select the torso on object mode
change to edit mode and PASTE THE LEG (CTRL+V)

If I'm right, now you have a leg into the vertices group of the torso and now you can link them!

Comment: I copied the legs with ctrl + C but when I tried to paste it on the "Torso" tab with ctrl + V, multiple tabs opened like: "Extrude Vertices", "Bevel Vertices", "New edge/face from vertices"... etc. The torso and the legs are still two different things(?), and sometimes the legs appear to be selected even tho I only have the torso selected and I think that's pretty weird

Comment: I think you may want to go through Blenderguru's Blender for Beginner's  tutorial before jumping into character modelling